# Best practise when making post request in JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, web, jax-rs

I have seen some different conventions regarding the response status code, when making a post request using JAX-RS.

I have seen this:

```
  Response.ok(//content or object).build();
```

My initial thought would be that this is wrong, since status code 200, just means ok, which is a broad term, but since we have 'Posted', I think 201 would be better since it also returns the URI of the element inside the header

```
 Response.created(//content or object).build();
```

here is want i want to achieve:

```
  @POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createUser(String content) throws CityNotFoundException
{
    ReceivedCreateUser receivedUser = gson.fromJson(content, ReceivedCreateUser.class);
    User createdUser = userFacade.createUser(receivedUser.name,
                                             receivedUser.email,
                                             receivedUser.password,
                                             receivedUser.city,
                                             receivedUser.gender,
                                             receivedUser.dateOfBirth);
    if(createdUser == null){
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return Response.ok(gson.toJson(UserDTO.basic(createdUser))).build();
```

}

i want to add the entity to the response, but `created` only accepts the uri not entities.

Comment: Then use 201 Created.

Comment: Yes, but then i can't give back the entity, that was created using the post method

Comment: `The 201 response payload typically describes and links to the resource(s) created.` (https://httpstatuses.com/201) What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I will update the question, and add code,

Comment: Cant you do a Response.created(uri).entity(entity).build()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not to return a 201 on a POST request depends greatly on the functionality behind it. If your end-point creates a new entity in the system then 201 would be the way to go, but POST is also often used to perform search request with large option sets. In this case a 200 or 204 would be desirable in case of results or no results.

But to return an entity with a POST and response 201 you could do something similar to this:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createUser(String content) throws CityNotFoundException
{
    ReceivedCreateUser receivedUser = gson.fromJson(content, ReceivedCreateUser.class);
    User createdUser = userFacade.createUser(receivedUser.name,
                                         receivedUser.email,
                                         receivedUser.password,
                                         receivedUser.city,
                                         receivedUser.gender,
                                         receivedUser.dateOfBirth);
    if(createdUser == null){
       throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return Response
       .created(new Uri("http://example.org"))
       .entity(gson.toJson(UserDTO.basic(createdUser)))
       .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Response.ok() is not Ok all the time, it might show that the request was done but actually no resource was created. You might want to use Response.created or Response.accepted. As in [this link](https://benramsey.com/blog/2008/04/http-status-201-created-vs-202-accepted/) , you can see that it all depends on the business logic of your backend.

Answer (score 0):

Response type is not the best return to clients and automatic documentation like Swagger, because it doesn't have too much information. I prefer particularly to return the entity directly how to bellow:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public UserDTO createUser(String content) throws CityNotFoundException
{
    ReceivedCreateUser receivedUser = gson.fromJson(content, ReceivedCreateUser.class);
    User createdUser = userFacade.createUser(receivedUser.name,
                                         receivedUser.email,
                                         receivedUser.password,
                                         receivedUser.city,
                                         receivedUser.gender,
                                         receivedUser.dateOfBirth);
    if(createdUser == null){
       throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return UserDTO.basic(createdUser);
}
```

This will return a `Status Code = 200`, but have many ways to change to 201. My favorite is overriding the `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter.filter(...)` as bellow:

```
import static org.springframework.http.HttpMethod.POST;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.CREATED;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class LocalContainerResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {
        if (POST.name().equals(requestContext.getMethod()) && OK.value() == responseContext.getStatus()) {
            responseContext.setStatus(CREATED.value());
        }
    }

}
```

This will change JAX-RS behavior returning 201 for all POST ok.

More 2 tips:

1. you can change a parameter (String content) to (ReceivedCreateUser content); and
2. you can put the code "`throw new WebApplicationException`" inside `userFacade.createUser(...)`